SAP UI5 Multiple File UploadSet Uploader locking error
I am using the uploadSet control to upload multiple files. I set the attribute instant upload to false so that the upload is triggered after you add a file to the table in the event "afterItemAdded" and the uploadUrl is set in the controller.
The files start the upload at the same time and then I get a lock error if one of the files finished before the other one.
How do I do so that it waits until one file is uploaded so that it uploads the next file?
In this moment this doesnt happen as afterItemAdded is called exactly at the time you add a file to the Table and  if you add many files then is called simultaneously for each file.
This is my view:
 <upload:UploadSet
                id="UploadSet"
                core:require="{ handler: 'analysisproject/ext/fragment/UploadFiles'}"
                multiple="true"
                mode="{= ${IsActiveEntity} === false ? 'Multiselect' : None }"
                showIcons="true"
                uploadEnabled="{= ${IsActiveEntity} === false}"
                terminationEnabled="true"
                fileTypes="txt"
                maxFileNameLength="100"
                httpRequestMethod= "Put"
                instantUpload="false"
                maxFileSize="2000"
                uploadButtonInvisible="{= ${IsActiveEntity} === true}"
                uploadCompleted="handler.onUploadCompleted"
                selectionChanged="handler.onSelectionChanged"
                afterItemAdded="handler.onAfterItemAdded"
                afterItemRemoved="handler.onAfterItemRemoved"
                mediaTypes="text/plain, text/csv"
                items="{path: '_UploadedFiles', templateShareable: false}">
            <upload:toolbar>
                <OverflowToolbar id="_IDGenOverflowToolbar1">   
                <Title id="_IDGenTitle1"
                    text="{i18n>files_title} ({_UploadedFiles/$count})"></Title>
                <ToolbarSpacer id="_IDGenToolbarSpacer1"/>
                <upload:UploadSetToolbarPlaceholder id="_IDGenUploadSetToolbarPlaceholder1" />
                <Button id="_IDGenButton1"
                    text="{i18n>delete_selected_files_button}"
                    enabled="false"
                    visible="{= ${IsActiveEntity} === false}"
                    press="handler.onMultiDelete"/>
                 <SearchField id="_IDGenSearchField1" width="auto" core:require="{ handler: 'analysisproject/ext/fragment/UploadFiles'}" 
                 search="handler.onFilterExtractedFiles" />
                </OverflowToolbar>
            </upload:toolbar>
            <upload:items>
                <upload:UploadSetItem id="_IDGenUploadSetItem1"
                        fileName="{FileName}"
                        mediaType="{FileType}"
                        url="{FileContent}"
                        visibleRemove="{= ${IsActiveEntity} === false}"
                        visibleEdit="{= ${IsActiveEntity} === false}">
                </upload:UploadSetItem>
            </upload:items>
        </upload:UploadSet>

and this the method afterItemAdded in the controller :
onAfterItemAdded: async function (oEvent) {
        const oUploadItem = oEvent.getParameter("item");
        if (!oUploadItem) {
            return;
        }
        const context = this.getBindingContext();
        if (!context) {
            return;
        }

        const oUploadSet = this.byId("UploadSet");

        const oBinding = oUploadSet.getBinding("items");

        const attachmentContext = oBinding.create({

        });

        await attachmentContext.created();

let serviceUrl = (this.getModel()).getServiceUrl();

        // apply created context to the upload item and set upload url for
        oUploadItem.setBindingContext(attachmentContext);
        oUploadItem.bindProperty("fileName", { path: "FileName", value: oUploadItem.getFileName() });
        oUploadItem.bindProperty("url", { path: "FileContent" });

        // setting the url manually because .bindProperty does not work here
        oUploadItem.setUploadUrl(
            serviceUrl  + "/FileContent"
        );

            // perform actual upload
            await (oUploadItem.getParent()).uploadItem(oUploadItem);


        }
    },

